# I have made a shape in xml and I have a problem giving it transparent and blur color

Tags: android, xml

this is my output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXUAv.png

this is expected :
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrnDA.png
I have made a shape in xml and I have a problem giving it transparent and blur color. how should I do it here's my code to the xml:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   >
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
   <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
   
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't give blur using shape, the shape can max be transparent but can't be a blur. To easily blur just use some library instead of creating bitmap on canvas and then tweaking the properties.

Here is some example.

[Blur view](https://androidexample365.com/an-easy-and-fast-library-to-apply-different-shaped-blur-effect-on-images/)

Answer (score 0):

May you like this :

**blur_img**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gradientRadius="40dp"
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:type="radial" />
    <size android:width="70dp"
        android:height="70dp"/>
</shape>
```

and **main_img**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blur_img"/>

</layer-list>
```